# Can we use JSON body format when doing Opencart API

Tags: php, opencart

right now im learning about Opencart API. form opencart documentation [Documentation](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/system/users/api/) every example write with json format.

however when i test it on postman. i test API for add product to cart. i can't put the json raw format body. i need to put the data on form-data.

this example result when i put raw json body format. and return empty array

[image]

and this result wheni put data on form-data

[image]

does opencart can't receive json format when do API call?

Comment: Why do you want it to be JSON?

Comment: @CodeCaster because in opencart documentation example write in json format. and i dont have any referense that API opencart use JSON format or not when post the data? so the answer is API opencart by default can't use JSON body format to send  the data? isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> opencart documentation Documentation every example write with json format.

No, it doesn't.

The examples use [a Python library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) and Python syntax.

The value of `data` looks **superficially** like JSON but is Python. The library takes that data and, according to the docs, converts it to form encoded data.

> data – the body to attach to the request. If a dictionary or list of tuples [(key, value)] is provided, form-encoding will take place.

---

The API doesn't appear to support JSON.

Comment: ah i see. thank you for the info. really confuse because on opencart doc doesn't explain about it